# How to remove pseudo-element styles from the first element?

Tags: html, css

Can some one help me to figure out how to remove the first line from left, as shown in the next img

[image]

And this is my CSS code:

```
.col-sm-6:after {
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #DDD;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Aboud, you seem to need a border attribute, which isn't in the code. And try not to use the afters, and before attributes.

Comment: CSS seems to be incomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

```
.col-sm-6:first-child:after {
    height: 0;
}
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/sepij/1/edit)**

Comment: Thank you, i'll use your advice next time.